# How can I ask for my salary to match what the person I'm replacing got?

Tags: salary, ethics, negotiation

In the next week or so I'll be having a meeting with my manager to discuss the promotion I recently got. I'm taking over the role of a work-mate who is currently serving his notice period. I know how much he got paid and I also know that the offer I'm going to get will be slightly less.

How do I properly/ethically say "I know (Joe Bloggs) got £xx,xxx a year, can you match that for me?"

I work for a large company with a huge budget, so that's not a problem.

Comment: "I work for a large company with a huge budget, so that's not a problem." Maybe you should clarify this? I don't even think you're using the word "budget" right. They probably have a very tiny budget for you, so that is a problem.

Comment: It is difficult to mention that per se, because of the taboo of the salaries (which, if you think about it, only benefits the companies, not the employees). I would use a similar figure and mention it in a more generic way, like "the market price for that position is around GBPxx,xxx, that's what I am expecting."

Comment: If anything, you should be aiming to get the salary Joe Bloggs got on day 1 of his promotion to his current position, not the salary he is on after having gained x years experience in the position.

Comment: Wilf have you considered that Joe might be older, more experienced and got yearly raises? Get a Salary that pays your bills, not Joe's.

Comment: @Scott Corrected for inflation.

Comment: " I also know that the offer I'm going to get will be slightly less." - I would be snapping their hand off to shake on the deal then. Usually you would get significantly less as you don't have that experience yet

Comment: If Joe Bloggs received a salary less than your last, would you take a pay cut? No - you'd say that your rate is your rate, and that it's not your problem if the market has changed to give you more leverage - that's how capitalism works. So why wouldn't you accept the same proposition in reverse?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

> How do I properly/ethically say "I know (Joe Bloggs) got £xx,xxx a
>   year, can you match that for me?"

Talk about what salary you feel you deserve and the value you bring to the company. Don't talk about what someone else made or makes - it's not relevant.

Would you take less if Joe Bloggs was making less than you? No, of course you wouldn't.

While in some domains, a specific number is assigned to a specific role, for the most part companies typically assign a salary range to a particular role. It's very common for folks promoted into a role to enter on the low end of that range.

You have 0 months experience in this new role. Most likely Joe Bloggs had more. It wouldn't be unusual if Joe Bloggs got raises during the time he held this role.

Concentrate on you, not others.

Comment: the salary you make should be based on objective facts, like your experience and the value of your work to the company, not your negotiating skills. (unless you work as a negotiator...) Facts like the salary the company pays for similar positions, or for similar expectations is relevant.

Comment: Ontop of this 100% accurate answer, keep in mind that Joe Bloggs' increased salary may have contributed to his firing

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Firing? Serving his notice period in the US usually doesn't mean they've been fired. It usually means they've found another position, job, company they're moving to, or retiring, etc....

Comment: Market is relevant. You vs Joe Bloggs is market.

Comment: "Would you take less if Joe Bloggs was making less than you? No, of course you wouldn't."
Boom. +1 You are not negotiating for Joe anyone, you are negotiating for _you_

Comment: If the company wants to replace Joe, and keeping another person's salary, most likely Joe was paid more. Why? Because it's a business loss to use a higher paid employee for a low paid position. 99% of the cases, they try to save and hire a junior someone to work in a senior position, pay them less and save $$$. Source : experience, got 50% raise at another company after declining to accept another senior person's job for free at the current one.

Comment: @njzk2 - While Joe gave you some affirmation with his "perhaps that's as it should be" comment. I think he was way to generous. I think your view is a surefire way to achieve mediocrity among the employees. When you come up with the objective formula for how much value a person brings to a company then you'll probably win a Nobel Prize. Until then the best that can be done is setting your own value and convincing companies that you are worth what you are asking. Either they perceive you to be worth it or not. What someone else makes has no relevance. No 2 people are the same or even similar.

Comment: @Dunk I don't think there is a formula for measuring the value a person brings. But there is certainly a value the company puts on the job it expects.

Comment: @Dunk the company's BATNA is to hire someone else.  We don't know how much "someone else" would want.  If the predecessor left voluntarily, we can surmise that the predecessor's salary was not enough.  If it was easy to find a candidate below that salary, the company would have already done it.  An alternative to negotiated agreement (not necessarily best) is to counteroffer the predecessor and that would require more money.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that makes sense. But I have observed also that the negotiating skill of someone plays a big role in the salary they obtain. (I guess I am jealous because I am not a good negotiator, but I am also annoyed because that has nothing to do with the value of the work)

Comment: @njzk2 - Negotiating skill plays a HUGE role in the salary people obtain. But that's how it should be. The company wants to hire people low and the employee wants to be paid high. Now it is the negotiation that settles on the final number. Why should someone who was willing to take whatever is offered get paid the same as someone who is willing to walk away unless the pay matched their expectations? The value of the work only sets the range of pay the company would be willing to pay, not how much each person is actually paid. That pay range could be a $50,000 spread for some positions.

Answer (score 14):

You don't. What Joe Bloggs makes is no one's business but Joe's, and perhaps the guy who signs his cheques. You're also assuming old Joe makes more than you, which might not be the case.

What you should do instead is research the average income for your new role and responsibilities, so say instead:

> The average income of a Foo Engineer in the general area is £x, given my experience in the company / expertise with the product / sunny disposition I'd like to see a figure of £x + y.

The only problem is, in a salary negotiation [the one who names a figure first loses](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2012/01/23/salary-negotiation/). The best tactic  is to ask management how much *they* think you're worth.

> So then, new job, new responsibilities, should I expect a salary increase to match?

If they respond with a figure below the market average you've already researched, you can use that as a lever instead. If their figure is *too* low then maybe you should start drafting your notice letter as well.

Good luck

Comment: +1 for the first two paragraphs, -1 for the third. That myth is an utter falsehood and hurts more than it helps.

Comment: @Lilienthal It's been [discussed on this site before](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/183/9549) but that question was about initial salary negotiation, not negotiating a raise / promotion. [jmac has given an excellent answer here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/11368/9549) discussing negotiating a raise, which seems far more appropriate. I'll amend my answer to reflect his advice. Cheers

Comment: At this point we may just want to create a new question about that old classic because I see it come up at least once a week. As mentioned [here](http://www.askamanager.org/2012/04/when-a-candidate-wont-share-salary-expectations.html) (external) there *is* some value to that advice but a plain "first to give a number loses" is so black-and-white that it's silly.

Comment: -1. One, Lillenthal's point. Two, not sure if you mean average or median. Three, you just posted beautiful advice for how to negotiate your salary *up to* the middle, and given that it's a negotiation, presumably take a haircut below that.

Comment: @djechlin In my example I name the average x and the desirable figure x+y. That's not up to the middle, it's up to the middle between x and y, if we get pedantic. I probably mean median, I confuse the two all the time

Comment: They're negotiating *against* you too. They don't hear x and y and take x+y / 2. They want to pay you below the average as much as you want to be paid above the average. So if you go with this strategy be prepared to hear about how you have less than average experience or a host of other arguments they're ready to make and you're not.

Comment: Once you mention "average" you've just given them the normative leverage that all they have to do is show you why you're worth a bit less than average, and you have no room to argue.

Comment: Furthermore what does average even mean? By city, years of experience, company? That company with that many years of experience? Java, C++, Ruby on Rails, full stack? Masters or bachelors? Ivy or community college? What hired.com says? What other people in your graduating class made? Be prepared to see statistics for what "average" is that you *don't* like. They will have data, you will not be able to argue against it because it will be correct. You just won't like it. (This happened to me in a negotiation once. We correctly refused to even read the report.)

Comment: I strongly disagree. What that other person made is relevant to the value the company place in the job being asked in this position.

Comment: @njzk2 I don't think that's always entirely correct. Sometimes, the other person might be what the company was valuing so high - not necessarily the position.

Comment: The OP says "I know how much he[Joe Bloggs] got paid"

Comment: @DoubleDouble possible, but then finding a replacement is looking for a chimera.

Answer (score 7):

Some questions to ask to yourself

1. Do you have the same education as Joe
2. Do you have the same work experience as Joe
3. Do you think that you will perform at this job position the same as Joe, 
   or even better
4. Has Joe earned this salary from day one

You have to compare same situations and don't get greedy. You don't have to mention Joe's salary. What I would do is I would allow some room for negotiation but not immediately, in like 3-6 months. You can ask your boss during the meeting, that you know that it will be your first time for this assignment but you are definitely sure that you can deliver even better results and if that's the case ask if they will be willing to renegotiate salary in 3-6 months.

Comment: It's the other way around. You are taking Joe's responsibility because they want it that way. They already think you can do as good or better. Regardless of education and such.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider it improper for you to *know* what "Old Joe" made, and therefore I would not reveal any such knowledge.

You received a promotion *(congratulations ...!)* and you are there to discuss an offer. Do you consider this compensation to be fair and appropriate *("nevermind old Joe ...")* for **you?**

Effectively, the company is "buying a product," namely, "your professional services." Are they offering to pay an agreeable price?  If you *seriously* believe that they are offering less money than you would or should accept, then you should be prepared to present counter-arguments at the negotiating table ... ***"nevermind*** "Old Joe!"   Joe's not the one who's negotiating, and he's not the one who's going to get the money ... *you* are.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion could go roughly as follows. First, you state that you expect (suspect, know for sure) that Joe Bloggs was making more money than are being offered to you. Second, you compare the value you would be producing for the company on your new position as compared to the value produced by Joe Bloggs. This is where things get tricky.

If Joe Bloggs is moving to greener pastures (or higher up etc.), he might be worth even more than he was paid, and might have been producing that much of value. So, you (a) propose some tangible performance goals that might be a bit less than Joe Bloggs' real achievements, but are in line with the salary he had. And then (b) try to meet or exceed them.

Your position is strenghtened by the fact that they could not keep Joe Bloggs on this position for these money, so you don't *have* to be as good as him to be worth that much.

Comment: -1 because you are not talking about you, but talking about some ex-employee Joe and makes you seem entitled. The best way to get what you want is talk about you.  How would you like if you were being paid _less_ because that's what Joe was being paid?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid If he was paid less and left, _and_ I would be as good as him, I'd follow suit unless I would be paid more. It's the market. I do not understand how you read "entitled" into my answer.